# Using XSLT to remove empty/unwanted nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML file with lots of unwanted/unneeded data that I would like to clean up using XSLT

Here is a small snippet of the data with example empty nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="xxx">
    <Tablix3>
        <Tablix13 Textbox1164="TAX SUMMARY" Textbox10="">
            <table26 textbox155="code">
                <Detail_Collection>
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                    <Detail textbox198="" TaxText2="" textbox112="0" textbox114="0" textbox200="0" textbox202="0" textbox874="0" />
                </Detail_Collection>
            </table26>
            <Tablix26>
                <table24>
                    <Detail_Collection>
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                        <Detail textbox208="" textbox209="" textbox210="0" />
                    </Detail_Collection>
                </table24>
            </Tablix26>
        </Tablix13>
    </Tablix3>
</Report>
```

I would like to delete for example all the empty (with no value or value of 0 in the attributes) detail nodes, and only if all detail lines were empty, also delete the detail collection node.

I would like to keep the tables in place as it occasionally has attribute data that I need.

I have tried using Xpath but having difficulty with my limited knowledge.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XSLT, start with an identity template that copies things unchanged:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then add empty template rules for the nodes you want to delete.

> "I would like to delete for example all the detail nodes"

that would be

```
<xsl:template match="Detail"/>
```

In your revised question:

> I want to delete all detail lines IF the attributes are empty or 0, e.g. if Detail textbox198=""

that becomes

```
<xsl:template match="Detail[@*[not(. = '' or . = 0)]]"/>
```

> "and only if all detail lines were empty, also delete the detail collection node."

With the same definition of "empty", that would be

```
<xsl:template match="Detail_Collection[not(Detail[@*[not(. = '' or . = 0)]])]"/>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Sorry for my vagueness, I have updated the OP. I want to delete all detail lines IF the attributes are empty or 0, e.g. if Detail textbox198="", then I would like to delete it.

Comment: I have edited the answer to answer the changed question. (Something I hate doing, by the way).

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the updated solution, my mistake for leaving out critical info.

Am I doing this in the right way? I am adding a XSL header, using your 1st code snippet, then applying a 2nd template with your 3rd code snippet but my output still has "empty" detail lines as in the sample above (no error). I have also tried using the 3rd snippet without the close tag at the beginning of the 1st template but this also does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would need to see the full stylesheet.

Comment: This is what I have at the moment (is there any way to format in the comments section?

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Detail[@*[not(. = '' or . = 0)]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

I have also tried adding the 3rd snippet as a 2nd template and using your 1st snippet as is.